# How to add positioning in srt files

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles

Am creating a very simple srt file for a video.

```
    1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,999 X1:0 X2:0 Y1:0 Y2:0
770 mA,10 mA,0 mV,


2
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:01,999 X1:0 X2:0 Y1:0 Y2:0
70 mA,20 mA,0 mV,
```

According to the wiki page this should position the subtitles at the place I have given. This is not happening in the vlc player. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is it working correctly in other players besides VLC?

Comment: Maybe not a direct solution to your problem, but there exists a lot of software that was designed specifically to build .srt and .ssa files. The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip) article shows basic usage.

Answer (score -1):

No software exist for this purpose
Rendering posions though require player support Quick time player does that, this file might play with proper positioning on APPLE TV, I know it supports simple tags like X1:0 (line at the top - only one tag required)